# My Mac SDK's Xcode 6.2 Build Error

Tags: c++, macos

Not too sharp with C++, but usually resolve issues by searching. Couldn't find anything on this...

Build (APP Target) in XCode 6.2  and I get this error,

> The run destination My Mac is not valid for Running the scheme 'APP (xxxx project)'. xxxx.app doesn't have any SDKs to build for My Mac. You can change xxxx.app's Base SDK or Supported Platforms to support My Mac.
>
> xxxx.app doesn't have any SDKs to build for My Mac. You can change xxxx.app's Base SDK or Supported Platforms to support My Mac.

FYI - Base SDK is macosx10.5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message for one project that I have downloaded from the Internet, this should do the trick:

Click on Project in left panel to opet Project settings, switch to "Build settings" tab. There you should set "Base SDK" to 10.9 or whatever, and set the Arhitectures to "Standard arhitecture (64-bit Intel)".